# redirecting a subdomain to a domain using htaccess

Tags: redirect, subdomain

I would like to redirect a subdomain to a folder in its main domain. 
 The subdomain is blog.mydomain.com and I would like to redirect it to http://www.mydomain.com/blog.

I have tried to do this using an htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond 5{HTTP-HOST} ^blog.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [PT,L]
```

but it doesn't work (the redirection does not happen).

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.mydomain.com/blog
```

If that doesn't work,i'll try something else